# Angular CLI Deploy to Github Pages issue: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes

Tags: javascript, angular, hosting, github-pages, static-site

I'm trying to deploy my Angular SPA app to github pages using this https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-github-pages .

I run this command `ng build --prod --output-path docs --base-href learningangular`

learningangular is the name of my github repo.

Here are the routes

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: "", redirectTo: "/abc", pathMatch: "full" },

  { path: "abc", component: OtherComponent },
  { path: "lazy", loadChildren: "./lazymodule/lazy.module#LazyModule" },

  {
    path: "example",
    loadChildren: "./ExampleModule/example.module#ExampleModule"
  },
  {
    path: "projects",
    component: ProjectsComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: "",
        component: ErrorPage
      },
      {
        path: ":id",
        component: ProjectDetailsComponent
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

when I open github.io/learningangular, it re-routes to github.io/learningangular/learningangular/ and gives the error

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'learningangular'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'learningangular'
```

what am I doing wrong?

I'm using

```
 "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
 "@angular/cli": "1.5.0",
 "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running the command `ng build` with the wrong parameter for `--base-href`. It needs a parameter of the following form `https://YOUR_GITHUB_USERNAME.github.io/PROJECT_NAME/`.

It seems that the github wiki information is not exact in this case.

Comment: Hi, I did this and now it doesn't even load the app. 

I get errors 

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()`

my new html base site is `<base href="https://alamgirqazi.github.io/learningangular">`

Comment: It loks like you forgot the `/` at the very end of your `--base-href` parameter. That is why the resources are not loaded and your app doesn't run. Set it to `https://alamgirqazi.github.io/learningangular/`

Comment: that was it. THANK YOU.